# could not cast value of type 'Swift._ContiguousArrayStorage<Swift.AnyObject>' to 'NSMutableArray'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsmutablearray, anyobject

I accidently updated iOS version in my phone from 10.3.3 to 11.0.3. Because of that I had to upgrade my xcode to latest 9.1 version. Now when I run my code in xcode 9.1 it appears

> could not cast value of type
>   'Swift._ContiguousArrayStorage' to 'NSMutableArray'

It seems to be there is no longer conversion from 'AnyObject' array to 'NSMutableArray'. But I have used this conversion throughout my code. I have spend almost a day trying using [[String : AnyObject]] instead [AnyObject] which was not a good idea as it affects throughout the code and it feels like I'm doing my code again from the scratch. Can anyone please suggest a better solution.?

Comment: Can you show your code?  Why are you using NSAnything with Swift?

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11. I just got the answer. Let me post it.

Comment: @Paulw11 I used "NSMutableArray" because I'm using this third party ObjC library. When I initialize the object I have to pass "NSMutableArray" as a parameter.

Comment: Try using my answer below.

(sorted as NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it by using

> (MyAnyObjectArray! as NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

instead of

> MyAnyObjectArray as! NSMutableArray

When I used xcode 8.3.3 and swift 3.2 use of .mutableCopy() was a error prone. But now it sees to be ok to use. Kind of confused. :(

Comment: `NSMutableArray(array: MyAnyObjectArray)` is probably nicer, but be aware that with your code or my code if the objective C actually mutates the array then those mutations won't be reflected in `MyAnyObjectArray`

Answer (score 1):

As I see this just in comments and in my opinion should be accepted answer :

```
NSMutableArray(array: anyObjectArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT-4.**

> SORTING OF NSARRAY OR MUTABLEARRAY IN SWIFT

If you have NSArray then it should be done easily. And if you have NSMutableArray, please refer this one.

```
    var ary_country:NSMutableArray = []
    print("Before ",ary_country) //"A", "E", "D", "B"
    let sorted = ary_country.sorted {($0 as AnyObject).localizedStandardCompare($1 as! String) == .orderedAscending}
   ary_country =  (sorted as NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
   print("After", ary_country) //"A", "B", "C", "D"
```